# Shopware 6: How to Access Config Parameters in Twig Template of the Admin Module

Tags: php, twig, shopware, shopware6

I'm looking for a way to access configuration parameters in twig template of the admin module. I tried to access it by:

```
{{ shopware.config.pluginName.config.fieldName }}
```

The problem is that in the twig template of the admin module `{{ shopware.config }}` isn't available. I tried to access it by `{{ dump(shopware.config) }}` but it returns nothing.
Am I doing something wrong?

Is there alternative to access plugin's configuration parameters in the admin module?

Is there a way to pass php variables to twig template of the admin module?

Thanks in advance,

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use following service:

```
this.systemConfigApiService.getValues('domain', this.selectedSalesChannelId)
```

where domain is the Plugin name.

Of course, you should inject that service first

```
inject: ['systemConfigApiService']
```

Using that service you can provide config value to twig template.

Comment: Search for class SystemConfigApiService in shopware vendor folder to get more information/methods

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to help you access global configuration via

```
{{ dump(config('core.listing.fieldName')) }}
```